# Como pegar o que foi retornado de uma Task

Tags: c#, thread

Tenho seguinte código:

```
                List<UserItem> items = null;
                Task taskCreateItems = new Task(() => items = DeliverItems(Session, Item.GetBaseItem(i), (priceAmount * ((Item.Items.Count > 1) ? Item.Items[i] : Item.Amount)), ExtraData, (Page.MinRank > 1), Item.songID));
                taskCreateItems.Start();
```

Este é o antigo código:

```
var items = DeliverItems(Session, Item.GetBaseItem(i), (priceAmount * ((Item.Items.Count > 1) ? Item.Items[i] : Item.Amount)), ExtraData, (Page.MinRank > 1), Item.songID));
```

Com antigo código eu conseguia pegar o que foi retornado, ex: items.count, items[0], mas no novo código usando Task eu não sei como posso fazer isto.

Comment: Está com cara de que isto não resolve o que espera que resolve, mas tentou `taskCreateItems.Result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se estiver tentando fazer com que esta instrução funcione sem interromper a operação do código em execução, recomendo utilizar um `TaskFactory`.

> **Observação:** se for uma aplicação STA/Windows Forms, coloque esta linha no método de carregamento do aplicativo:

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThread = false;
// isso irá desativar as verificações de acesso aos membros feitos
// por threads em que os invocadores não fazem parte do Thread atual.
```

Após isso, faça isso no seu código:

```
// declare a variável onde será utilizada pelo thread
List<UserItem> items = null;

// isso mesmo. Declare esse void dentro do void que você está
// trabalhando. isso será um sub-void.
void editarItems () {
     items = DeliverItems(Session, Item.GetBaseItem(i), (priceAmount * ((Item.Items.Count > 1) ? Item.Items[i] : Item.Amount)), ExtraData, (Page.MinRank > 1), Item.songID));
}

// inicie o thread
new System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory().StartNew(editarItems);
```

Veja funcionando no [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mJRMZk), junto com um trecho indicando se o método foi executado ou não.

---

> **Importante:** a declaração de sub-voids só funciona se estiver utilizando o compilador do C# Roslyn 2.0 ou superior, que vem instalado por padrão no Visual Studio 2017 e 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Após o `taskCreateItems.Start();`

Coloque `var str_recebida = await taskCreateItems;`

Não esquecer que tem de colocar a funçao como Async por exemplo:

```
private async void btn_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```